delete the facebook saved app using php codeigniter
Can any body help me how to delete the facebook saved app using php codeigniter.
Here is my code first i load the fb library then how to delete the the specific app using this library?
Here is my code first i load the fb library then how to delete the the specific app using this library?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
